# Microdisplacement Ocean Modifier Dicing Artefact on Adaptive Subdivision

Tags: subdivision-surface, ocean-simulation

hay , i recently learn to make large ocean using displacement from baking ocean modifier, but i have problem issue with the dicing artefact. i already try to play with dicing rate 1px-4px. but the result is same just it good in far camera angle. i already using 2 sub modifier.

here the result
the close from camera
[image]

and the far from camera is look fine

[image]

here the subdiv setting
[image]

Comment: Hello :). There simply isn't enough geometry. You can increase the *Max Subdivisions* field to maximum of 16. Other than that, you'll need to add more subdivisions before the adaptive subdivision modifier is applied.

Comment: hay, i already have 4 sub level before sub n my poly reach 3 million. the max sub i try in 15 but it still same issue,..but if i make dicing rate to 4px same the preview it's look fine but less detail.

Comment: Hey :). Well, even 3 million vertices might not be enough for an ocean. Just in case - is your mesh smooth shaded? That might help a bit in the flatter areas.

Comment: i think i already have a answer, i juts try to change the interpolation method to smart, but the detail is gone